# Why is this list comprehension valid

Tags: python, syntax

I was surprised that `[x for x in range(10) if x is 5 not in range(10) if True]` is valid (Python 3.6). How is it parsed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Comment: Its gibberish. It depends on execution order of things . x is 5 is only True for 5. if True in range(10) is always False. result is an empty list. why formulate such a thing?

Comment: @PatrickArtner What depends on the execution order here…? The list is empty because `5 not in range(10)` is always false… (and `x is 5` depends on the small integer interning of your Python flavour…)

Comment: @deceze I ment operation order - the `is` is evaluated first, True or False in range(10) is always False

Answer (score 3):

> Common syntax elements for comprehensions are:
>
> ```
> comprehension ::=  expression comp_for
> comp_for      ::=  ["async"] "for" target_list "in" or_test [comp_iter]
> comp_iter     ::=  comp_for | comp_if
> comp_if       ::=  "if" expression_nocond [comp_iter]
> ```
>
> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least
>   one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the
>   elements of the new container are those that would be produced by
>   considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left
>   to right, and evaluating the expression to produce an element each
>   time the innermost block is reached.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries

There can be more than one `for` or `if` clause, which each just form nested `for`/`if` blocks, so this really just unrolls to:

```
res = []
for x in range(10):
    if x is 5 not in range(10):
        if True:
            res.append(x)
```

The `x is 5 not in range(10)` is a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), equal to `x is 5 and 5 not in range(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as the following "unrolled" structure:

```
my_list = []
for x in range(10):
    if x is 5 not in range(10):
        if True:
            my_list.append(x)
```

`x is 5 not in range(10)` just a weird condition that is read as
`(x is 5) and (not (5 in range(10)))` (credit to Matthias `:)`), but `5` is always in `range(10)`, so this is kind of weird.

When you have multiple `if` clauses like this, you just think of them as nested if statements, so it's equivalent to

```
[x for x in range(10) if x is 5 not in range(10) and True]
```

Their actual use-case is when you also want to have another inner loop inside an if clause, eg a contrived example:

```
[i + j for i in range(10) if i & 1 for j in range(4) if j & 1]
```

which is the same as

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    if i & 1:
        for j in range(4):
            if j & 1:
                my_list.append(i + j)
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) I would read `x is 5 not in range(10)` as `(x is 5) and (5 not in range(10))`

Comment: @Matthias Good point! Thank you for spotting that, I'm clearly rusty

Comment: I didn't trust my ability to understand the documentation and tested with `5 == 5 in range(2, 10)` and `(5 == 5) in range(2, 10)` and got different results.

Comment: Of course the usage of `is` is the next crucial point. If we have `(x is y) in range(1, 2000)` and define `x = 5` and `y = 5` we get `True`. Using `x = 1000` and `y = 1000` we get `False` (due to caching of small integers in CPython). But OK, this is commenting on code that we all agree to be rubbish anyway.

Comment: @Matthias You're making that even trickier with the added parentheses there. With `(x is y) in range(1, 2000)`, you depend on small integer interning of your Python flavour to end up with `True/False in range(1, 2000)`. Now, `True` happens to be represented as `1` internally, so results in `True`, while `False` (`0`) is not in that range. Try `True in range(2, 2000)`… However, `x is y in range(1, 2000)` is the entirely different `x is y and y in range(1, 2000)`.

Comment: @deceze I know. This is beyond the basic question. My main point was the usage of `is` in the context of the caching (interning) of small integers. I could have reduced the example to `x == y` vs. `x is y`.